# how to inject custom template in extension in default page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, template

I am trying to inject template code in default customer account login page.

I have created a template file under

vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/templates/custom_template.phtml

How can I inject it in default customer login page ? I tried to inject it by creating a layout file under vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/ directory but after clearing cache and checking storefront, it does not seem to be working.

Can anyone provide suggestion on how to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout file vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml

**replace template**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                   <argument name="custom_template" xsi:type="string">vendor_name_module_name::custom_template.phtml</argument>
               </action>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
```

**add new content** using container **customer.login.container**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="customer.new" name="custom.template" template="vendor_name_module_name::custom_template.phtml"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
```

**add new content** using container **form.additional.info**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.template" template="vendor_name_module_name::custom_template.phtml"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
```

**add new content** using container **content**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="content">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.template" after="customer.login.container" template="vendor_name_module_name::custom_template.phtml"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.Yes, it works but it replaces the default login page, I am trying to add custom code just below the "Create an account" button. Instead of setTemplate, is there any method available which lets add a code to  existing templates.

Comment: Don't mention it. I added some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file `module_directory/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml` in your module with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Your_Module::custom_template.phtml" name="custom.template" after="customer.new"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You should aslo add `Magento_Customer` to your module.xml `sequence` element